# Change class of UICollectionView to PSTCollectionView in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, pstcollectionview

My application is supporting iOS 5.1+. And I want to use `UICollectionView` in my application.

But `UICollectionView` is not available prior iOS 6.0 versions. So I used famous third party library [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). It has solve my all class related errors.

Now problem is in my `XIB` I have used `UICollectionView` control. When I build application I get following error for `XIB` only:

```
error: Class Unavailable: `UICollectionView` on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

I tried to change the parent class of `UICollectionView` to `PSTCollectionView` but it is not showing there any such class in listing.

How can I solve this `XIB` related problem.

Comment: Most probably this wont work, but have you tried to set the custom class in the XIB (in the identity inspector) for the collectionView control to the PSTCollectionView one...

Comment: @Emilio yeah, But it is not working, In identity inspector it is not showing any of the PSTCollectionView class.

Comment: I fear being two different classes without any relation the way to go (although painful) is distinguish the iOS version and use one or the other depending on that (separate implementations)

Comment: @Emilio PSTCollectionView manage itself according to iOS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of this problem I removed xib from my project. And converted my UIViewController class to subclass of UIView. And added that class as a subview wherever it was required.